# Rails Server Doesnt Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I was updating my apps gem using `bundle update`, the but gems stopping "updating" half way thru. I had to restart the console, and run bundle update again, but now I'm getting this error when trying to start the rails server. I also tried `gem install aws` but it didnt change the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    30: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    29: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    28: from /Users/chrisbedoya/Desktop/CustomGarments/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/chrisbedoya/Desktop/CustomGarments/bin/spring:14:in `require'
    26: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    24: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    22: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    21: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    20: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    19: from /Users/chrisbedoya/Desktop/CustomGarments/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /Users/chrisbedoya/Desktop/CustomGarments/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    17: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    15: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    14: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    13: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    12: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    11: from /Users/chrisbedoya/Desktop/CustomGarments/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
     9: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
     8: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
     7: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
     6: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
     5: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     4: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
     3: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-aws-0.4.1/lib/carrierwave-aws.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-aws-0.4.1/lib/carrierwave-aws.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-aws-0.4.1/lib/carrierwave/storage/aws.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-aws-0.4.1/lib/carrierwave/storage/aws.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- aws/s3 (LoadError)
```

Comment: There is a latest version 1.3.0 of carrierwave-aws in rubygems.org (https://rubygems.org/gems/carrierwave-aws/versions/1.3.0). Try updating the Gemfile with the latest version (unless you have specific reason for using the older version). You can also find the runtime dependency in the same rubygems.org link.  For version 1.3.0, aws-sdk-s3 ~> 1.0 is noted as one of the runtime dependency and for your version 0.4.1, it is aws-sdk >= 1.29. Checkout the installation section https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby for details about installing the aws sdk.

Answer (score 0):

This is seems your problem 
`/Users/chrisbedoya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/carrierwave-aws-0.4.1/lib/carrierwave/storage/aws.rb:1:in 'require': cannot load such file -- aws/s3 (LoadError)`

I think that you should put this line in your `Gemfile`, and run `bundle install` again.

`gem 'aws-sdk'`

hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you already have the aws gem in your Gemfile: stopping or crashing bundler while it does its business can cause all sorts of problems on multiple levels. I'd recommend clearing your gems and installing everything again.